# Remove Epiphany 3.2 after installing it from a PPA?

Tags: ppa, uninstall, purge

I installed epiphany 3.2 via ppa at webupd8.org to check out the webapp feature. tried it but its not for me. i removed the ppa in the software sources, and did remove --purge, but it is still there and installed. even after a log out. how can i remove epiphany 3.2 from ubuntu (11.10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ppa-purge for this kind of thing. Doing the following steps in a terminal should get you where you need.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge webupd8team/gnome3
```

We take a moment to add the webupd8 PPA again, because ppa-purge needs to figure out what is in the PPA. ppa-purge itself removes the PPA and replaces everything you got from there with the original version from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Epiphany Does not require a PPA. You can safely remove the ppa as per Dylan's instructions.

To uninstall epiphany, [click here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/epiphany-browser) and click on Remove in the opened Software Center.

You can safely uninstall epiphany even if you leave the PPA enabled, ie you don't need to install `ppa-purge` at all.

**Update**: To remove it, you can just add the PPA, and go to software center to remove it easily. I was able to do it easily this way.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Then go to [Software Center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/epiphany-browser) and remove Epiphany.

Comment: I wanted to use webapps with Ubunut 11.10 and epiphany 3.2 that is why I used the ppa, the software centre has epiphany 3.0. I should have mentioned in my question that I did try removing with software centre and that did not work.